# libGDX. Скриншот сделанная с андроида не сохраняется в самом же андроиде

Tags: java, libgdx

Проблема в том что при нажатии например по дисплею должно сохраняться скриншот экрана но этого не происходит, изображения просто нет не в галерее не в другом месте, при этом если протестировать для десктоп версии то скрин успешно сохраняется.
Я делаю рисовалку для андроид с сохранением работы но я не знаю каким еще способом можно сохранить картину на андроиде.

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);
        for (int i = 4; i < pixels.length; i += 4)
        {
            pixels[i - 1] = (byte) 255;
        }

        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.local("mypixmap.png"), pixmap);
        local = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath().toString();
        System.out.println(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath());
        System.out.println(Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath());
        pixmap.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `external` вместо `local`

```
PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.external("mypixmap.png"), pixmap);
```